# How do I define an exception for line breaks in Vim?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, file-type

I edit files in Vim were I log terminal command lines along with descriptions of what I did.
All my command lines start with $, so my files look like this:

> ```
> This is a description of what this
> command does, it can be quite long and
> should have line breaks.
>
> $ ./the_command.sh
> ```

These are actually [Viki](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=861) files, but I guess this question should apply to any file type. I have filetype detection on and the files are correctly identified.

The question now is:

I want (hard) line breaks to be inserted into all the text except for the actual copies of command lines, which could be easily identified by the leading $.

Is it possible in Vim to define an exception for applying the line break rule based on a pattern? Would I do that in the syntax file for viki files?

UPDATE
Using a combination of what Herbert and Jefromi suggested, I now have this in my .vimrc:

```
au CursorMovedI *.viki call SetTextWidth()

function! SetTextWidth()
    if getline(".")=~'^\$'
        set textwidth=1000
    else
        set textwidth=80
    endif
endfunction
```

It does exactly what I want. Thanks guys!

Comment: Just to clarify: I want the linebreaks to be inserted automatically as I type. In my .vimrc I have a line "autocmd FileType viki setlocal textwidth=80" to set the textwidth specifically for viki files, which works fine except that it breaks up my "$ COMMAND" lines as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gather when you say you want "hard line breaks" you mean you want Vim to break a line automatically, as when it reaches a textwidth column.  The best way to do this, I think, is to define an 'au' command that sets textwidth to a high number (higher than longest possible line) when it's on a line that begins with a "$".

So something like this would change textwidth whenever you enter or exit insert mode on a line:

```
au InsertEnter call SetTextWidth()
au InsertLeave call SetTextWidth()

function! SetTextWidth()
    if getline(line('.')) =~ '^\$'
        " [edit: 'set textwidth = 0' is preferable to line below]
        set textwidth =1000
    else
        set textwidth=78
    endif
endfunction
```

You might want to use the CursorMoved/CursorMovedI groups instead of InsertEnter/Leave since they're more fine-grained.  They get triggered whenever you move the cursor, so the function ends up getting called lots more times, but function is simple enough that it's probably not going to introduce any noticeable degradation in performance.

For doing without a function at all you could probably use something like this:

```
au InsertEnter exec "set tw=" . getline(line('.'))=~'^\$' ? 1000 : 78
au InsertLeave exec "set tw=" . getline(line('.'))=~'^\$' ? 1000 : 78
```

Comment: You could probably use `CursorMovedI` to manually implement line wrapping, and leave textwidth alone.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. Should it not be simply "getline('.')" instead of getline(line('.')) though? The problem with this approach is that it only works if you start to edit a line, type the "$" and then get out of and back into insert mode. Otherwise there is no "$" at the beginning of the line when you enter INSERT, which means that line breaks will be inserted and therefore there is no leading "$" in the current line when you exit INSERT mode either. I have to try with CursorMovedI now, I guess that should work.

Comment: @tospo -- Yes, you correctly point out the limitation with InsertENter/Leave solution.   Since I rarely start and complete a line of text of 78 or more characters without going out of insert mode at least once that's not a problem for me.  Plus, if you're aware of the limitation and entering a long line you can just make sure to <esc> out of insert and then go back in to get the textwidth change.  I prefer this to having the event code running every time I move the cursor, but for this particular solution the only problem with CursorMoved is probably imagined in my head.

Comment: The only situation where it doesn't work yet is when I paste something - no line breaks will be applied in that situation. It's not too much of a problem but just out of interest: how could I capture that event? Couldn't find anything in the list of Vim events. I thought that CurcorMoved would do the trick but I guess setting textwidth in NORMAL mode wouldn't work anyway, right? Is that what you meant with manually implementing line wrapping?

Comment: @Herbert: usnig the CursorMovedI event doesn't seem to have any noticeable negative effect on Vim on my system, so I think it should be ok.

Comment: @tospo -- For pastes one solution would be to remap the 'p' (and 'P') key to something like this 'nmap p :call DoPaste()' and then have a DoPaste function that either resets tw or uses the 'paste' option, like this:  'function DoPaste() | set paste | normal p | set nopaste | endfunction'

Comment: Sorry, that would be ':nmap p :call DoPaste<cr>'

Answer (score 2):

I believe this would meet your criteria:

```
set textwidth=78
v/^$/normal gq/^$\|\%$^M
```

`^M` is `ctrl-v` followed by `enter`

Lets break this down into smaller peices

`/^$\|\%$` is a pattern that matches every line not starting with a $. The `\%$` will include the lines between the last $ started line and the end of file.

`gq/^$\|\%$` formats from the current line up to the pattern `/^$\|\%$`

`:normal {cmd}` executes a normal mode commands on current line.

`:v/pattern/` is equivalent to `:g!/pattern/` which executes a command on every line lot matching /pattern/

This solution does not format as you type as @Herbert Sitz solution does. Instead formats the text in one fell swoop at the end.

You could of course apply this before each write with

```
au BufWritePre filename-pattern-here set textwidth=78 | v/^$/normal gq/^$\|\%$^M
au BufWritePost filename-pattern-here set textwidth=0
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. I'll go with Herbert's simply because I prefer to have those linebreaks applied while I type but thanks for the explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure what you want (you should be a bit more specific on where (why, how) you want to insert hard line breaks), but you can issue a command like

```
:v:^\s*$: <Your command to insert line break, e.g. s/something/\r/ >
```

This above command searches for any line which does not start with any whitespace followed by a `$`, then executes the command you specify.

HTH

Comment: as I said, I want the hard line breaks everywhere in the file except for lines starting with $ (copies of command lines). I want those line breaks to be inserted on the fly, i.e. by setting the textwidth vairable (which I have done specifically for the viki filetype). So what you suggest is not quite what I was looking for, thanks anyway!

Comment: OK, now I get it. In this case, you should consider the other answers.